# db->query crashing in mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, mysqli

This function is supposed to return `false` when it fails, but in my case it isn't returning anything, instead it crashes.

```
echo "This gets printed" ;
$x =  $db->query( "SELECT * FROM something WHERE id=123 AND name='abc'" );
echo "This does not get printed";
```

now if I echo the actual query string, copy paste it into mysql from the command line, it is a valid query. The only thing I can think of is that it might have to do with the fact that it is a recursive query, and it might be invalid to call `$db->query` twice in a row. Here is more or less my flow:

```
function recursiveQuery ( $result )
{
   $temp = array ();

   while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )
   {
      $temp [ 'name' ] = $row [ 'name' ];
      $id = $row [ 'id' ];
      $temp [ 'sub' ] = recursiveQuery ( $db->query( "SELECT * FROM something WHERE parent_id=$id" ));
   }

   return $temp;
}

recursiveQuery ( $db->query( "SELECT * FROM something WHERE parent_id=0" ));
```

Is this not valid? How should I reorganize it?

Comment: Why dont you just use a JOIN?

Comment: it's for folders, so there can be an infinite number of joins

Comment: Your function will never return the expected result if you have more than just 1 item at any level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I am such a fool. Turns out, the problem was scope, namely, `$db` was not accessible from inside recursive query